# Compare string of time in mysql with current time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli

I have a column **Time_Start** of type string to save time in my DB.

Time is saved in **`23:59`**  format.

I need to compare values in my column with the current time! here is my mysql query:

```
$result =   mysqli_query(
  $conn, 
  "SELECT * FROM Adds WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Time_Start, '%h:%i') > CURTIME()" 
);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) 
{ 
  echo "NO RESULTS" ;
}
else
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) 
  {
    echo  $row['Time_Start'];
  }
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should not store times as string.

Comment: you forgot to start your statement with a " - simple parse error.

Comment: no i ran it. It shows no results! changed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %H. your input is 24 hours format.

```
select STR_TO_DATE(Time_Start, '%H:%i');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the designated column type `TIME` to store your time data. Time will be stored in format `hours:minutes:seconds` and comparison with current time is really easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Adds Time_Start > CURTIME()
```

Comment: I already know that. I am just curious to know how to convert a string to time and then compare it to CURTIME()